# Azure Mobile Service InvokeApi missing in Xamarin

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

Anybody has a clue how to Invoke a Custom API in Windows Azure Mobile Service from a Xamarin Client using MobileServices SDK for Xamarin component?

Seems that the method InvokeApiAsync is missing in MobileServiceClient class.

Thanks!

Gutemberg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest update (1.1.0) of the Mobile Services component brings it up to full feature parity with our other client SDKs, including Custom API support.

Comment: Yep, my request on User voice was implemented :D

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently a way to invoke a Custom API from a Xamarin Client using the Mobile Services component.  The component is currently being updated, however, so that functionality should be there very soon.

Comment: That makes the Mobile Services pretty useless :( but thanks for the reply

Comment: There hasn't been a checkin on the Github site for the component in 3 months. Where is the component being updated ?

Answer (score 0):

Used this in a sample project recently and can verify that LoginAsync work and is included in the Azure Mobile Services SDK for Xamarin.